# Xamarin.Forms HybridWebView do nothing in API 23

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, hybrid-mobile-app

In Xamarin.Forms I have a HybridWebView that works fine in API 19 android. But don't work in API 23. I didn't test for other. My Xamarin and target API is the last one and update.

My question is why this is not going to work on API 23?

here is my Hybridwebview

```
namespace MyNameSpace.CustomRenderer
{
public class MyHybridWebView : View
{
    public bool Loaded { get; set; }
    public bool TimeOut { get; set; }

    public bool Terminate { get; set; }

    public void TerminateLoading()
    {
        Terminate = true;
    }

    public int ContentHeight { get; set; }
    public double Progress { get; set; }

    public void OpenLinkExternally(string url)
    {
        Device.OpenUri(new Uri(url));
    }


    Action<string> action;

    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "Uri",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(MyHybridWebView),
        defaultValue: default(string));

    public static readonly BindableProperty LoadHtmlCodeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "LoadHtmlCode",
        returnType: typeof(string),
        declaringType: typeof(MyHybridWebView),
        defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }
    public string LoadHtmlCode
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LoadHtmlCodeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LoadHtmlCodeProperty, value); }
    }

    public void RegisterAction(Action<string> callback)
    {
        action = callback;
    }

    public void Cleanup()
    {
        action = null;
    }

    public void InvokeAction(string data)
    {
        if (action == null || data == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        action.Invoke(data);
    }
}
```

}

Here is my android renderer:

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyHybridWebView), 
   typeof(MyHybridWebViewRenderer))]

namespace MyNameSpace.Droid.Renderers
{
public class MyHybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<MyHybridWebView, 
  Android.Webkit.WebView>
  {
       public bool _loadJS = false;

    public new static string Tag = "MyHybridWebViewRenderer";
    private static MyHybridWebView _xwebView;

    const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){jsBridge.invokeAction(data);}";


    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyHybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        _xwebView = e.NewElement as MyHybridWebView;

        if (Control == null)
        {

            var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(Forms.Context)
            {
                ScrollX = HorizontalScrollbarHeight,
                HorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false,
                VerticalScrollBarEnabled = false,
                ScrollBarSize = 0,
                Settings =
                {
                    JavaScriptEnabled = true,
                    DomStorageEnabled = true
                },                   
            };
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new ExtendedWebViewClient());

            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {

            Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");

            var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as MyHybridWebView;
            hybridWebView.Cleanup();
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            if (_loadJS)
                return;


            var webView = e.NewElement as MyHybridWebView;
            Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");


            InjectJS(JavaScriptFunction);

            _loadJS = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (Control == null || e.PropertyName == null)
            return;

        if (e.PropertyName == "LoadHtmlCode")
        {
            if (Element.LoadHtmlCode != null)
            {

                Control.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", _xwebView.LoadHtmlCode, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

            }



        }
    }

    void InjectJS(string script)
    {
        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("javascript: {0}", script));
        }
    }


    private class ExtendedWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {

        public override async void OnPageFinished(aWebView view, string url)
        {

            DebugLogger.WriteLine("Start OnPageFinished ===========>");
            if (_xwebView != null)
            {
                var i = 120; //times of trying to get content 
                const int timeStep = 250; // millisecend

                await Task.Delay(500);
                while (i > 0) // wait here till content is rendered
                {
                    if (_xwebView.Terminate || _xwebView.Loaded)
                        break;

                    await Task.Delay(timeStep); //times of getting content                       

                    DebugLogger.WriteLine("Set WebView Height ============>" + view.ContentHeight , Tag);

                    _xwebView.HeightRequest = _xwebView.ContentHeight = view.ContentHeight + App.WebViewOverSize;
                    i--;
                }

                if (view.ContentHeight == 0 || i == 0)
                {
                    _xwebView.TimeOut = true;
                }
                await Task.Delay(500);

                _xwebView.HeightRequest = _xwebView.ContentHeight = view.ContentHeight + App.WebViewOverSize;

                DebugLogger.WriteLine("Content Is Loaded with height :" + (view.ContentHeight) + " =============>", Tag);
            }

            base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
            view.ClearCache(false);

      }



        public override void OnPageStarted(aWebView view, string url, Bitmap favicon)
        {

            if (!string.Equals(url.ToLower(), "file:///android_asset/") &&
                !(url.ToLower().Contains("https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/") &&
               (url.ToLower().Contains(".jpg") || url.ToLower().Contains(".png"))))
            {
                _xwebView.OpenLinkExternally(url);
                view.StopLoading();
                return;
            }

            base.OnPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }


     }


  }

}
```

And Here is My jsBridge as common:

```
namespace MyNameSpace.Droid.CallcSharpFromJs
{
public class JSBridge : Java.Lang.Object
{
    readonly WeakReference<MyHybridWebViewRenderer> hybridWebViewRenderer;

    public JSBridge(MyHybridWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer)
    {
        hybridWebViewRenderer = new WeakReference<MyHybridWebViewRenderer>(hybridRenderer);
    }

    [JavascriptInterface]
    [Export("invokeAction")]
    public void InvokeAction(string data)
    {
        MyHybridWebViewRenderer hybridRenderer;

        if (hybridWebViewRenderer != null && hybridWebViewRenderer.TryGetTarget(out hybridRenderer))
        {
            hybridRenderer.Element.InvokeAction(data);
        }
    }
}
```

}

And Here is my javascript

```
function invokeCSCode(data) {
    invokeCSharpAction(data);
}


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var $lg = $('.lightgallery');

$lg.lightGallery(); 

// Perform any action just before closing the gallery

$lg.on('onBeforeClose.lg', function (event) { invokeCSCode("OnCloseLightGallery"); });


// Perform any action just after opening the gallery

$lg.on('onAfterOpen.lg', function (event) { invokeCSCode("OnOpenLightGallery"); });

...
```

I extremely need your help. Please kindly support me.

Comment: By doesn't work, did you receive any exception? Or just it doesn't render your html?

Comment: No Exception, does not render my javascript

Comment: I should mention in emulator API 23 everything work good. But in real device it is not.

Comment: You mean in your real device it just display a blank white  page?

Comment: this line $lg.lightGallery(); is nothing to do with my problem and execute. But invokeCSCode function is not execute and nothing happened. I mean in API 23 I see lightGallery but the function is not execute.

Comment: Please post your whole html code.

Answer (score 0):

@York Shen - MSFT
Here is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>

<!--------------------- styles ------------------------>

<!---------- Light Gallery css  lightgallery - v1.2.22 - 2016-07-20 http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/ --------->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/Content/CSS/lightgallery.min.css" type="text/css" media="all">


<!--------------------------------- jquery v3.6 stable ---------------------------------->
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/Content/JS/jquery.js"></script>

<!------ light gallery script dynamically gets the height according to device height ------>
<!-- here we copy and paste the light gallery script and change the height property dynamically by screen size like height:"627" -->
<script>
/*! lightgallery - v1.2.22 - 2016-07-20
* http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/
* Copyright (c) 2016 Sachin N; Licensed Apache 2.0 */


</script>

<!--------------------------------- App script ---------------------------------->
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/Content/JS/AppScript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p>اولین چینی توربو در بازار ایران</p>

<div class='lightgallery percent-20'><a class='large' title='جک اس 5 - جک S5 ' href='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-8.jpg'><img src='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-8-800x500.jpg'></a><a title='جک اس 5 - جک S5 ' href='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-7.jpg'><img src='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-7-200x150.jpg'></a><a title='جک اس 5 - جک S5 ' href='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-6.jpg'><img src='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-6-200x150.jpg'></a><a title='جک اس 5 - جک S5 ' href='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-5.jpg'><img src='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-5-200x150.jpg'></a><a title='جک اس 5 - جک S5 ' href='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-4.jpg'><img src='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-4-200x150.jpg'></a><a title='جک اس 5 - جک S5 ' href='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-3.jpg'><img src='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-3-200x150.jpg'></a><a title='جک اس 5 - جک S5 ' href='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-2.jpg'><img src='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-2-200x150.jpg'></a><a title='جک اس 5 - جک S5 ' href='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-13.jpg'><img src='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-13-200x150.jpg'></a><a title='جک اس 5 - جک S5 ' href='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-12.jpg'><img src='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-12-200x150.jpg'></a><a title='جک اس 5 - جک S5 ' href='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-11.jpg'><img src='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-11-200x150.jpg'></a><a title='جک اس 5 - جک S5 ' href='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-10.jpg'><img src='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-10-200x150.jpg'></a><a title='جک اس 5 - جک S5 ' href='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-توربو.jpg'><img src='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-توربو-200x150.jpg'></a><a title='جک اس 5 - جک S5 ' href='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5.jpg'><img src='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-200x150.jpg'></a><a title='جک اس 5 - جک S5 ' href='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-9.jpg'><img src='https://dande6.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/جک-S5-9-200x150.jpg'></a></div>


</body>
</html>
```